# Installing grunt-cli package through npm fails on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, gruntjs, npm

I can't install grunt on windows 7

I'm trying to install it via this command:

```
npm install ‐g grunt‐cli
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g grunt-cli
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Windows\System32\-g
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Windows\System32\grunt-cli
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\System32\-g
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\Windows\System32\-g'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\System32\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: I think you need to change your folder I wouldn't install a package under C:\Windows\System32\

Comment: It looks like it's trying to treat the `-g` flag as a package to install. Can you verify that you're using a standard dash character for the flag? Can you try to do the same with `npm install --global grunt-cli`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the order of arguments from:

```
npm install ‐g grunt‐cli
```

to

```
npm install grunt-cli -g
```

Cheers!